# Yahoo pipes - any way to combine items?

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-pipes

I'm working on a pipe and am having trouble with combining two lists of items.

```
List 1:
[0] letter - a
[1] letter - b
[2] letter - c

List 2:
[1] word - apple
[2] word - banana
[3] word - cake
```

I'd like something which emits the following:

```
List 3:
[1] letter - a
    word - apple
[2] letter - b
    word - banana
[3] letter - c
    word - cake
```

I can't figure out for the life of me how to do this simple operation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is Yahoo pipes?

Comment: @PhiLho Yahoo pipes are used to use many commands to get done your needs..... here is link for the further info. http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/

Comment: I have a same kind of problem. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018784/yahoo-pipes-combine-2-rss-feeds-whereby-title-of-new-feed-consists-of-titles-of][1]. 

Please help me!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18018784/yahoo-pipes-combine-2-rss-feeds-whereby-title-of-new-feed-consists-of-titles-of

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is verbose and complicated to do in Yahoo Pipes. If you still want to go through the trouble, here's my solution:

In this example, List 1 is a Yahoo search for "apples" and List 2 a Yahoo search for "oranges".

1. The [main pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=dN3Kj0TQ3RGOQHxfQBJ3AQ) starts with a list of numbers. This list is cut to the length of List 1.
2. Then for each number n, [the n-th item of List 1](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit#aNjs2ETQ3RGEU_FYQBJ3AQ) is attached to the numbered item.
3. Then for each number n, [the n-th item of List 2](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit#7CccDUXQ3RG5327zBB50VA) is attached to the numbered item.

Finished.

You probably want to clean things up a bit. Add a proper title, remove the number value, etc.

Notes:

1. I used [alto maltés](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/person.info?eyuid=BFSiVIoypHc8yva5CXQMmG0aaQ--)' list of numbers. It's not a part of Yahoo Pipes, so it might stop working.
2. I used two n-th item pipes. Maybe this can be simplified.
3. If List 2 is shorter than List 1, the last element of List 2 is used. This should be easy to change if necessary.